# How to fix a jave.lang.RuntimeException?

Tags: java, android, logcat

This worked at one time. I dont know what I did to kill it. App Force close before any thing happns.
Below is the LogCat

> 10-21 15:34:14.503: E/AndroidRuntime(22129): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bigtexapps.android.DropBubble/com.bigtexapps.android.DropBubble.Menu}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bigtexapps.android.DropBubble.Menu in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.bigtexapps.android.DropBubble-2.apk]

Below is the Android Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.bigtexapps.android.DropBubble"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
         android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity    android:name=".Menu"
         android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
<action      android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         </activity>

 <activity android:name=".DropBubble"> </activity>

  <activity android:name=".Help"> </activity>

 <activity android:name=".GameOver"> </activity>


  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Below is the first part of the Menu.java:

```
package com.bigtexapps.android.DropBubble;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.menu.MenuScene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.menu.MenuScene.IOnMenuItemClickListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.menu.item.IMenuItem;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.menu.item.SpriteMenuItem;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
/**
 * @author Roger Belk
 * 
*/
 public class Menu extends BaseGameActivity implements IOnMenuItemClickListener{

// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 320;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
protected static final int MENU_START = 0;
protected static final int MENU_HELP = MENU_START +1;
protected static final int MENU_QUIT = MENU_HELP + 1;

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================
private Camera mCamera;
private MenuScene mMenuScene;
private Scene mMainScene;
private Texture mStartBackGroundTexture;
private TextureRegion mStartBackGroundTextureRegion;
private Texture mStartGameTexture;
private TextureRegion mStartGameTextureRegion;
private TextureRegion mHelpTextureRegion;
private TextureRegion mExitTextureRegion;

public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT, 
        new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT),this.mCamera));   
}

public void onLoadResources() {
    //To import background of resources
    this.mStartBackGroundTexture = new Texture(512, 512, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
    this.mStartBackGroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mStartBackGroundTexture, this, "gfx/startbg.png", 0, 0);
    //Import to start the game resources
    this.mStartGameTexture = new Texture(256,256,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mStartGameTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mStartGameTexture, this, "gfx/menu_start.png",0,0);
    this.mHelpTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mStartGameTexture, this, "gfx/menu_help.png",0,50);
    this.mExitTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mStartGameTexture, this, "gfx/menu_quit.png",0,100);

    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.mStartBackGroundTexture,this.mStartGameTexture);
}

public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.createMenuScene();
    this.mMainScene = new Scene(1);
    final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mStartBackGroundTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT -      this.mStartBackGroundTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
    final Sprite bg = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mStartBackGroundTextureRegion); 
    this.mMainScene.setChildScene(this.mMenuScene, false, true, true);  
    this.mMainScene.getTopLayer().addEntity(bg);
    return this.mMainScene;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not bundled the jar with your apk. What you need to do is just configure your build path settings and check the export option from eclipse for corresponding jars.

Comment: I have never had to check the export boxes before. Thanks, It was a shock to see the app work again I had been looking at it for 4 days trying to figure out what I did to kill it. LOL I can retype the code by heart I have focused on that being the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is here:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bigtexapps.android.DropBubble.Menu
```

Make sure any 3rd party jar files are in your project's /libs folder.

In older versions (r16 and lower) the way to handle this was to put your 3rd party jars into any folder, and then add that folder to your project's path.  Google changed this in r17 so that all 3rd party jar files are placed in to /libs.

Comment: They were in the right folder and added in the path way, I just didnt check for them to be exported(see checked answer)